# Specifying default file name for asp.net core static folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I currently have a generated index.html, js and other static files living in a folder and I'm marking that folder as a static folder (by adding the following in the Configure method in Startup.cs:

```
   app.UseDefaultFiles();
   app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
    {
        FileProvider = new Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, @"../build")),
        RequestPath = new PathString("/app/")
    });
```

Is there a way to set index.html as the default response for this */app route? Because right now localhost:5000/app/ returns a 404 while localhost:5000/app/index.html returns the index.html.

EDIT: I missed to mention that I did try using app.UseDefaultFiles() like mentioned in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files#serving-a-default-document) but it does not work for me. The server still returns a 404

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files#serving-a-default-document

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the comments in that [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files) has clarified it:

> Kieren_Johnstone
> Featured May 22, 2017
>
> The section, "Serving a default document" misses some vital
> information.  If you configure your UseStaticFiles to work off a
> non-root RequestPath, you need to pass the same FileProvider and
> RequestPath into both UseDefaultFiles and UseStaticFiles, it seems.
> You can't always just call it as stated in the section.

So that means, you should write something like this to enable your specified folder to provide a default page:

```
    app.UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions()
    {
        FileProvider = Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, @"../build")),
        RequestPath = new PathString("/app/")
    });
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
    {
        FileProvider = Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, @"../build")),
        RequestPath = new PathString("/app/")
    });
```

Comment: This is still the case for .NET Core 5.0, in case someone runs into it.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // Serve my app-specific default file, if present.
    DefaultFilesOptions options = new DefaultFilesOptions();
    options.DefaultFileNames.Clear();
    options.DefaultFileNames.Add("mydefault.html");
    app.UseDefaultFiles(options);
    app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```

For more details follow this link:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files
and go to section: "Serving a default document"
```

Comment: he has index.html, UseDefaultFiles() includes it by default, no need to add mydefault.html

Answer (score 1):

from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files#serving-a-default-document):

> Setting a default home page gives site visitors a place to start when
>   visiting your site. In order for your Web app to serve a default page
>   without the user having to fully qualify the URI, call the
>   UseDefaultFiles extension method from Startup.Configure as follows.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles(); // For the wwwroot folder

    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"build")),
        RequestPath = new PathString("/app")
    });
}
```

> UseDefaultFiles must be called before UseStaticFiles to serve the
>   default file.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I tried this, but still returns a 404. Does this work if a different static folder (other than wwwroot) is used?

Comment: @ArvindVenkataraman, where is you app folder located physically?